# I created a custom object, and fellow admins cannot see my data

Tags: administration, security, sharing, profile, roles

I'm part of the System Administrator role/profile. I created a custom object and added some data to it. Other system admins created data as well. When creating the object, we assign ourselves as the Owner of that record. We cannot see each others data. Why would this be?

Note: Sharing is allowed for the object. Under Security Controls -> Sharing Settings, Default Extranet and Intranet access is *Public Read/Write*, and Grant Access Using Hierarchies is checked. There are no existing sharing rules for the object.

Note: One thing to mention is that these custom objects have "private" attachments attached.

Update: The issue is not security related, rather it seems that I was only viewing recent records. I was tricked by this, since the view name selected was 'All' -_-
[image]

Comment: is the option of deployed on the custom object checked ?Hope its still not in "in development"

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, The deployment status is "Deployed"

Comment: by role you mean profile ?This is really weird .

Comment: Copy the URL for a record you can see. Send it to another admin, have them open the URL - What Happens? Are you sure when they click on the tab that they are licking "Go" to view the records? (The initial page is a recent items and this trips many people up - Basic I know)

Comment: @Eric that advice helped, it _was_ just viewing recent records, but it was rather deceiving since the view was named "All". I've edited my question to show a screenshot, and if you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @contactmatt - Great, Added it as an Answer so you could accept and this does not keep getting bumped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the URL for a record you can see. Send it to another admin, have them open the URL - What Happens? Are you sure when they click on the tab that they are licking "Go" to view the records? (The initial page is a recent items and this trips many people up - Basic I know)